# Crosstab and pivot on Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table like so -

| entity | category | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 324 | Yankees | 132 |
| 983 | Orioles | 323 |

How do I return -

| entity | yankees_cnt | orioles_cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 324 | 132 | NULL |
| 983 | NULL | 323 |

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Snowflake

Answer (score 0):

This [PIVOT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html) SQL does what you have asked:

```
WITH data(entity,  category,  cnt) AS (
    select * FROM VALUES 
    (324     ,'Yankees',   132 ),
    (983     ,'Orioles',   323 )
)
SELECT * 
FROM data
PIVOT ( SUM ( cnt ) FOR category IN ( 'Yankees', 'Orioles' )) 
     AS p (entity  , yankees_cnt,  orioles_cnt);
```

gives:

| ENTITY | YANKEES_CNT | ORIOLES_CNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 324 | 132 |  |
| 983 |  | 323 |